# How to use addEventListener to element rendered by javascript instead of inline js

Tags: javascript

I don't want to see the inline js when I inspect the page.

```
const data = [
    {name: "A", desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor"},
    {name: "B", desc: "sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit"},
]

const container = document.querySelector(".container");
data.forEach(item => {
    container.innerHTML += `<div class="card" onclick="showDetail('${item.desc}')">${item.name}</div>`
})

function showDetail(desc) {
    console.log(desc);
}
```

Therefore, I want to use addEventListener, but I don't know how to access `desc` without render in HTML

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
cards.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
        stuck here...
    })
})
```

edit:

I watched a video on youtube. I can use `document.createElement` in `forEach`. Then I can use `addEventListener` on it.

```
data.forEach(item => {
   const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   newDiv.innerHTML = `...`;
   
   newDiv.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(item.desc))

   container.append(newDiv)
})
```

Comment: You should be able to use the index: `.forEach((card, i)` to then access `data[i].desc`

Comment: @ChrisG your method have a limitation of order. if the order change before catch it with `querySelectorAll` the `data[i]` and the `card[i]` will not be the same

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd like to commend you on wisely ridding your code of attribute event handlers, the next step in imptoving your code is to use event delegation.

[Event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) is the best way to listen and handle events under circumstances of a changing environment such as:

- listen for events for an unknown amount of elements
- listen for events on dynamically created elements

Event delegation leverages [event bubbling](https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing) and the very versitile [`Event Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). Basically, add an event listener to a parent element (`".container"`) of the tags (`".card"`) that the user will actually click. Then in the event handler, determine what happens to certian tags and exclude the rest.

***Details are commented in example below***

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".container");

const data = [{
    name: "A",
    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor"
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    desc: "sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit"
  }
];

/* Pass the event object */
const clickHandler = event => {
  /* This is .container -- parent element that 
     listens for the click event for it's child
     tags '.card'
  */
  const base = event.currentTarget;
  // This an array of '.card' within '.caontainer'
  const deck = [...base.querySelectorAll('.card')];
  // This is the actual '.card' that was clicked
  const item = event.target;
  // This is the index of the clicked '.card'
  const index = deck.indexOf(item);
  /*
  This condition ensures that only '.card' tags
  are clickable -- any other tag is ignored
  */
  if (item.matches('.card')) {
    console.log(data[index]['desc']);
  }
};

data.forEach(item => {
  box.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<div class="card">${item.name}</div>`);
});

box.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

```html
<section class='container'></section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data-attribute` for example:

```
data.forEach(item => {
    container.innerHTML += `<div class="card" data-desc="${item.desc}">${item.name}</div>`
})
```

Then into `addEventListener`:

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
cards.forEach(card => {
    card.addEventListener("click", () => {
        showDetail(card.dataset.desc);
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't want to see `desc`  in HTML because what if `desc` has 200 words, it doesn't look good in HTML.

Comment: So if the order will always the same you can use @Chris G comment for resolve your problem. Another tips if you used an unique ID into object data you can use it into data-attribute and call the desc into script.